# Android Multicast is only working using 255.255.255.255 address

Tags: java, android, sockets, network-programming, multicast

I tried setting the Multicast host as 230.0.0.1 using the port 5500. Then, on the other side I said to join group 230.0.0.1 at port 5500. It joined and it received packets for a few seconds. Then it stops all of a sudden. If I use 255.255.255.255 it receives packets normally. Why is this happening? The code for the Multicast sender is below:

```
private class StatusBroadcasterThread extends Thread
{

    private static final boolean DEBUG = App.DEBUG;
    private static final String TAG = "StatusBroadcasterThread";

    private DatagramSocket broadcastSocket;

    public StatusBroadcasterThread(int port) throws SocketException {

        broadcastSocket = new DatagramSocket(port);

        this.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (!this.isInterrupted()) {

            try {

                byte[] buffer = status.toString().getBytes(); 

                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, InetAddress.getByName(App.Config.multicastAddress),
                        App.Config.multicastPort);

                broadcastSocket.send(packet);

                if (DEBUG)                      
                    Log.d(TAG, "Sent: " + new String(packet.getData()));

            } catch (IOException e) {

                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            try {
                sleep(App.Config.broadcastInterval);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Receiver thread:

```
private class ReceiverThread extends Thread
{

    private static final String TAG = ComMessageReceiver.TAG + "Thread";

    private WifiManager wifiManager;
    private MulticastSocket multicastSocket;
    private InetSocketAddress groupInetSocketAddress;
    private boolean joinedGroup = false;

    public ReceiverThread(String group, int port, int timeout) throws IOException {

        super();

        wifiManager = (WifiManager) App.context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        groupInetSocketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName(group), port);
        multicastSocket = new MulticastSocket(port);
        multicastSocket.setSoTimeout(timeout);

    }

    public ReceiverThread() throws IOException {

        this(Config.multicastAddress, Config.multicastPort, DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        Log.d(TAG, "started");

        while (!this.isInterrupted()) {

            if (wifiManager.getWifiState() == WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED) {

                if (!joinedGroup) {

                    try {

                        multicastSocket.joinGroup(groupInetSocketAddress,
                                NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(getWifiInetAddress()));

                        wifiManager.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL, TAG);
                        wifiManager.createMulticastLock(TAG).acquire();

                        joinedGroup = true;

                    } catch (IOException ex) {

                        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to join Multicast group: " + ex.getMessage());
                    }
                }

                try {

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[256];

                    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);

                    multicastSocket.receive(packet);

                    Message message = new Message(packet);

                    Log.d(TAG, "message from " + message.getIp() + " " + message.getMsg());

                    for (MessageListener listener : listenerList)
                        listener.onMessageReceived(message);

                } catch (SocketTimeoutException ex) {

                    Log.e(TAG, "Timed out: " + ex.getMessage());

                } catch (IOException ex) {

                    Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
                }
            } else
                joinedGroup = false;
        }
    }

    InetAddress getWifiInetAddress() throws UnknownHostException {

        ByteBuffer wifiRawAddress = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
        wifiRawAddress.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).putInt(wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());

        return InetAddress.getByAddress(wifiRawAddress.array());
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, How were you testing this code? Using Android localhost or localnetwork?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.** `255.255.255.255` is **NOT** a **multicast address** but **BroadCast address.**

**2.** Please check that you are **properly closing the sockets** when the communication is completed.

See below the **list of all the multicast address..........**

```
224.0.0.0   Base address (reserved)
224.0.0.1   The All Hosts multicast group addresses all hosts on the same network segment.
224.0.0.2   The All Routers multicast group addresses all routers on the same network segment.
224.0.0.4   This address is used in the Distance Vector Multicast Routing Protocol (DVMRP) to address multicast routers.
224.0.0.5   The Open Shortest Path First (OSPF) All OSPF Routers address is used to send Hello packets to all OSPF routers on a network segment.
224.0.0.6   The OSPF All D Routers address is used to send OSPF routing information to designated routers on a network segment.
224.0.0.9   The Routing Information Protocol (RIP) version 2 group address is used to send routing information to all RIP2-aware routers on a network segment.
224.0.0.10  The Enhanced Interior Gateway Routing Protocol (EIGRP) group address is used to send routing information to all EIGRP routers on a network segment.
224.0.0.13  Protocol Independent Multicast (PIM) Version 2
224.0.0.18  Virtual Router Redundancy Protocol (VRRP)
224.0.0.19 - 21     IS-IS over IP
224.0.0.22  Internet Group Management Protocol (IGMP) Version 3
224.0.0.102     Hot Standby Router Protocol version 2 (HSRPv2) / Gateway Load Balancing Protocol (GLBP)
224.0.0.107     Precision Time Protocol version 2 peer delay measurement messaging
224.0.0.251     Multicast DNS (mDNS) address
224.0.0.252     Link-local Multicast Name Resolution (LLMNR) address
224.0.1.1   Network Time Protocol clients listen on this address for protocol messages when operating in multicast mode.
224.0.1.39  The Cisco multicast router AUTO-RP-ANNOUNCE address is used by RP mapping agents to listen for candidate announcements.
224.0.1.40  The Cisco multicast router AUTO-RP-DISCOVERY address is the destination address for messages from the RP mapping agent to discover candidates.
224.0.1.41  H.323 Gatekeeper discovery address
224.0.1.129 - 132   Precision Time Protocol version 1 time announcements
224.0.1.129     Precision Time Protocol version 2 time announcements
```

Comment: So if I want things to work I need to use one of these addresses?

Comment: Your 230.0.0.1 is well inside the multicast range..and `so it should work`..i have given you the list for reference... `Class D is used for multicast and its range is 224.0.0.0-239.255.255.255`

Comment: You said it worked for sometimes then it stopped working... i will suggest you to check your threads, you closing of streams, connections, check that whether server has stopped listening at 5500 port. use netstat -n/a to check the ports.

Comment: It says it is timing out. Take a look at the receiver thread please.

Comment: Try to `remove the timeout and do it`.................. I think its timing out, before the connection can be established, and also check your` Wifi-state`, there is a condition in your while loop, see its working or not.....

Comment: Ok I'll try this. But before I tried to change the tablets. It was a Motorola trying to multicast and the Samsung trying to receive. I tried to make the Motorola receive and Samsung to multicast, and it worked. Maybe this is a problem that has to do with the tablet?

Comment: TCP/IP stack will be same in all the devices, whether pc, tab, mobiles etc....... that wont change....... I am suspecting that there is a problem with your net connectivity from your tablet..... And i know you have done it...but still a remainder ... Permission like Internet, Network in to AndroidManifest