# Android multicast high packet loss

Tags: android, udp, multicast

I am trying to do multicast in android. I have three phones ( all Galaxy S5 ). One phone has Wifi tethering turned on and is acting as AP(mobile data is turned off). Of the other two phones, one is transmitting to a multicast address the other is receiving, with both connected to the AP of the first phone. The transmitting and receiving phone are kept side by side.
I found that of 1000 packets that I am sending, I am receiving only about 200. Below is an outline of how I am sending

```
MulticastSocket mMulticastSocket = new MulticastSocket(port);
InetAddress multicastGrp = InetAddress.getByName("239.255.255.250");
mMulticastSocket.joinGroup(multicastGrp);
String sendStr = "";
int packetSize = 1400;
for(int i = 0; i < packetSize; i++)
sendStr = sendStr+"a";

for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
mMulticastSocket.send(new DatagramPacket(sendStr.getBytes(), sendStr.getBytes().length, mMulticastSocket, port);
```

Receive is something like,

```
//acquire multicast lock
byte[] buffer = new buffer[2048];
DatagramPacket rPack = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
mMulticastSocket.setReceiveBufferSize(1024*64);
int recvCount = 0;
while(true) {
mMulticastSocket.receive(rPack);
recvCount++;
}
//release multicast lock
```

Both send and receive are done in worker threads. I also found that as the value of 'packetSize' reduces, the number of received packets is increasing. I guess it is due to CPU load or receive buffer, but in any case, I want to multicast packets of size 1400 bytes and receive as many as possible( I know that number of received packets is a function of the channel between the two phones but I think keeping them side by side is almost the best channel that can be had). Also, when I am doing a UDP unicast, i am able to receive about 900 of the 1000 packets sent.
I am not able to understand why the number of received packets is so low for multicasting. What is it that I am missing?

Comment: Do you unlock WifiManager.MulticastLock? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.MulticastLock.html also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634942/android-multicast-is-only-working-using-255-255-255-255-address

Answer (score 0):

Your server is sending packets as fast as possible.  There is nothing in your sender loop that would throttle back the data rate of the packets being sent.  So each packet is being sent microseconds apart.  Most likely something along the network stack will cause some buffers to fill up.  UDP has no built in flow control or congestion control.  If you can have some small delay (~1ms to 5ms) between packets, you will probably see much less packet loss.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    mMulticastSocket.send(new DatagramPacket(sendStr.getBytes(), 
    sendStr.getBytes().length, mMulticastSocket
    Thread.sleep(5, 0);   // quick hack to throttle back rate
}
```